# Matlab declare function with two different behaviours

Tags: functions, matlab

I'm struggling in finding a way to declare a function with two different behaviours in the following way:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
        \frac{\sin(x)}{x} & \text{if } x \neq 0, \\ 
        1 & \text{if } x = 0. 
        \end{cases} $$

Thanks

Comment: Try `help if`. ${}{}$

Comment: sorry but I can't understand, I'm new at matlab

Comment: Start Matlab and type the above.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example:

```
function y = f(x)
    if x==0
        y = 1;
    else
        y = sin(x)/x;
    end
endfunction
```

Here is a vectorised example:

```
function y = f(x)
    # return array must have same size as x...
    y = 0*x;
    # logical array with conditional...
    idx = x==0;
    y(idx) = 1;
    y(!idx) = sin(x(!idx))./x(!idx);
endfunction
```

Note that in the above it would make more sense to compute `!idx`, but the purpose is here to illustrate.